# Windows Media Player

Tags: c#, windows, registry, wmp

When you first open WMP, it asks you to configure it.
Once you do - where does it save that information ? In what Registry ? 
How can I programatically, using C#, know if WMP has been configured on my machine ?

Comment: You can start your own research with process monitor

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

Comment: Can't it be done without downloading any utility ?

Comment: Isn't that information stored in some registry ?

Comment: Yes. Probably this information stored in registry. This utility will help you find place. It can show you all registry read/write/query from process, and you can find exact place